# Put search bar next to logo

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie with HTML and CSS.

I can not figure out how to put the search bar next to my sample logo (this logo is only a placeholder for another one). Like how to access the search bar box.

Picture 1 is how it looks like:
[see pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A53Va.png)
Picture 2 is how I want it to look like:
[see pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBhqz.png)

My code so far:

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  padding-top: 50px
}
```

```html
<head>
  <header>
    <title>Meine Rezepte</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Suche" />
  </header>
</head>

<body> </body>
```

Can anyone help me?

I already tried it by div class, container, flex ... but nothing seems to work. If any it only changes the search bar itself.

(dont judge my code, I know for advanced developer it may look horrible)

Comment: Why do you have `header`, `img` and `input` within your `head` tag? `head` is for metadata only, not for visible elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally it's better to use this code in body section by the way, you need to use `display:flex` for header. search more about flex layout for feature cases.

now for handle the space between logo & input, you can change gap property or remove it and add margin to your image.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 200px;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  object-fit:cover
}
```

```html
<head>
  <header>
    <title>Meine Rezepte</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Logo">
    <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Suche" />
  </header>
</head>

<body> </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you **can't add** img, input etc inside your head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="content">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
      <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Suche" />

    </div>
  </body>

</html>


img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: I tried but nothing changes

Comment: Could you try like this?

Comment: the logo gets very large and the search bar is below it :'D

Comment: You can change img css as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

wrap your img and input in a div and style that div with the below styling :

```
div {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:flex-start
}
also place the img and input and the parent div inside <body>tag
```

Comment: nothing changes

Comment: You can't style a `link`

Comment: wrap the img and input in a div and then style that parent div with the above styling